# chown: taking ownership from other users

Tags: files, permissions

Say I have:

- A user `user1111` with ID `1111`
- A user `user2222` with ID `2222`
- A group `group3333` with ID `3333` that both the above users belong to

and I create:

- With `user1111`, a folder `a`
- With `user1111`, a file `a/b`
- With `user2222`, a file `a/c`

with the folder and both files having 777 permissions:

```
$ stat --printf='%a %u %g %n\n' a a/b a/c
777 1111 1111 a
777 1111 3333 a/b
777 2222 3333 a/c
```

I understand the implications of not allowing this as `user1111`:

```
user1111$ chown -v 2222 a/b
chown: changing ownership of 'a/b': Operation not permitted
failed to change ownership of 'a/b' from user1111 to 2222
```

I.e. it's OK not to allow the user to *assign* ownership to other users.

I don't understand why this is not allowed though:

```
user2222$ chown -v 2222 a/b
chown: changing ownership of 'a/b': Operation not permitted
failed to change ownership of 'a/b' from user1111 to 2222
```

I.e. why can't the user *take* ownership from another user?

Edit to add more info for @binarysta:

```
user1111$ chown -v user2222: a/b
chown: changing ownership of 'a/b': Operation not permitted
failed to change ownership of 'a/b' from user1111:group3333 to user2222:group2222

user1111$ chown -v user2222:group3333 a/b
chown: changing ownership of 'a/b': Operation not permitted
failed to change ownership of 'a/b' from user1111:group3333 to user2222:group3333

user2222$ chown -v user2222: a/b
chown: changing ownership of 'a/b': Operation not permitted
failed to change ownership of 'a/b' from user1111:group3333 to user2222:group2222

user2222$ chown -v user2222:group3333 a/b
chown: changing ownership of 'a/b': Operation not permitted
failed to change ownership of 'a/b' from user1111:group3333 to user2222:group3333
```

Comment: could you please try `user1111$ chown -v user222: a/b` ?

Comment: @binarysta Added more info into the question.

Comment: I don't understand - are you asking why it's not Ok for users to arbitrarily take over ownership of any file?

Comment: @muru Not of any file, but of files they are permitted to. If you're able to `rm` a file given the folder permissions - which you could in the above example - why are you not able to `chown` that file to yourself?

Comment: In the scenarios that you outline. It would be possible to write a `chown` to do this: using `cp`, and `rm`. But the chown syscall could not be used.

Comment: Your question is not easy to read: overly verbose, and a few other bits. It needs proof reading. e.g. "I.e. it's OK not to allow the user to assign ownership to other users." Does that mean that it is also OK to allow the user to assign ownership to other users. I would think that it is imperative not to allow the user to assign ownership to other users.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor "But the chown syscall could not be used." Yep I get that. I don't get why and that's what I'm asking.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor `Your question is not easy to read: overly verbose` Very strange remark, the bits I gave are pretty much all the gist in the spirit of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) `Does that mean that it is also OK to allow the user to assign ownership to other users.` Not sure how you read that or how the sentence is not clear. "OK not to allow" can be read "OK to forbid", if that's what was confusing to you. That is I understand the rationale behind not allowing current user -> other user switching. I could elaborate, but then I guess you'd complain it's even more verbose...

Comment: @levant why should I be able to take over ownership just because I can modify the containing directory?

Comment: @muru it is not exactily that you should. It is more that you can. Just copy the file and remove the original.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor would that change the ownership of another hardlink to that file?

Comment: @muru "why should I be able to take over ownership just because I can modify the containing directory?" Why not? Why forbid `chown` when can you do `cp b z; rm b; mv z b`, which effectively does the same thing?

Comment: @levantpied as I also asked ctrl-alt-deltor, **would that change the ownership of another hardlink to that file?** If not, it's **not** effectively the same thing

Comment: @muru Fair enough, it's not the same in that case. Let's say it would if it could, preserving the current behavior (i.e. if it can change all hard links, do that, otherwise fail with `Operation not permitted`, as it does now). What's the rationale in forbidding it completely instead?

Comment: That's not how this works. You're proposing a complex mechanism instead of a fairly simple one; the onus is on you to provide the rationale for implementing that complex mechanism, when the simpler one works fine for most use cases.

Comment: @levantpied where is `chgrp` already doing that? If you try to change the group of a file you don't own, you'll just get an error. For your simple use case, user1111 asks the system administrator to change the ownership, and they will do it.

Comment: @munu is correct, `cp` followed by `rm` is not the same. e.g. multiple hard links, inode number changes, create time changes, ... But as you say, there may be a use for a tool that does it this way (it should be a user-mode tool, not a kernel change. Could it be an extension to `chown`?, I don't know. Could you write a script to do it?, probably. ). You also say that `chgrp` already does work for hard links. It does not. It just follows the name/hardlink that you give it and updates the inode (once). This affects all names/hardlinks of the file.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my point as to what "complex mechanism" is. I'm not talking about updating the ownership of "on all the hard links." That is of course, meaningless - hardlinks are all the same file, just under different paths. There is only one thing to update. The complex mechanism is checking whether the user is allowed to recreate that file - which is what you're proposing as the criteria here - at which you point you need to consider ACLs, TOCTOU checks, etc. That's what's complicated.

Comment: @levantpied "chgrp updates all the paths" what paths? As to what things `chown` *could* do: *could* != *should*. "And chgrp doesn't have to do these? " If `chgrp` ever followed the criteria you're suggesting, it will have to. But it doesn't. This is the second time you're asserting that `chgrp` is doing something it doesn't. Please show evidence, or stop this nonsense. Don't ping me unless you have hard evidence that `chgrp` does the things you claim it does, please.

Comment: @muru If you have 3 hard links at 3 paths pointing to 1 file, chgrp updates all of the paths (through the virtue of all paths pointing to same file). "But it doesn't." So chgrp will update the group of any file without checking that the users has permissions do to that? `user2222$ chgrp group2222 a/b --> chgrp: changing group of ‘a/b’: Operation not permitted` "Don't ping me unless" No problem, I won't ping anymore.

Answer (score 2):

- Only root can change the owner of a file. The owner cannot transfer ownership, unless the owner is `root`, or uses `sudo` to run the command.
- The owning group of a file can be changed by the file's owner, if the owner belongs to that group. The owning group of a file can be changed, by `root`, to any group. Members of the owning group other than the owner cannot change the file's owning group.

> Setuid : when an executable file's setuid permission is set, users may execute that program with a level of access that matches the user who **owns the file**.

Being able to change the ownership of a file with non-privileged user can cause many security issues, for example:

- User can set the uid for an executable script then change the ownership to root, in this case the script will be executed by root privilleges.
- By changing ownerships there is no trace who has created a file really.
- Can cause disk quota issues if there are quota defined for each user.
- Only owner of the file can change permissions/metadata (`chmod`)

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question though. I'm not asking _what_ the user can do, but _why_ is the user not allowed to take the ownership of the file that it can otherwise fully access (read, write, rename, delete)?

Comment: @levantpied I added some reasons to the answer.

Comment: That's the current user -> some other user case, which I mentioned I understand the issues with. I'm specifically asking about the reverse: some other user -> current user case, which I don't see any issues with.

Comment: Why userA should be able to make itself the owner of userB's files? why there's no issue with that? As I mentioned it destroys the trace about ownership of a file. More important, only owner of a file can change the permissions/metadata (`chmod`) so a user can make itself the owner and then change permissions of files.

Comment: "Why userA should be able to make itself the owner of userB's files?" For similar reasons they can `cp`, `rm`, `mv`. If I'm `userA` and `userB` gave me sufficient permissions, why should I be able to `cp`, `rm` or `mv` it, but not `chown` it? "As I mentioned it destroys the trace about ownership of a file." So does `cp a b; rm a; mv b a`, so why not allow chown?. "so a user can make itself the owner and then change permissions of files." If I gave 777 permissions to them, what's the issue with that? That's my whole question - I _gave_ permissions to them, why can't they peruse them?

Comment: First, giving 777 permission to a file will not make a user to be able to `rm` or `mv` it. deleting a file requires write permission on the parent directory.

Comment: Second, there are many routines to avoid human mistakes or possible security issues, while a user can cp,mv,rm should not be able to change the ownership should have only cp,mv,rm privilleges. By design only owner can change metadata of a file so ownership cannot be changed with non-privilleged users.

Comment: for example, with `chattr +i file` (only possible with root) can make a file immutable, even with 777 nobody can modify or delete this file, even root itself cannot delete it. However, we know root can remove this attribute with `chattr -i file` and then delete the file, but it does not make sense root to be able to delete immutable files.

Comment: "First, giving 777 permission to a file" Of course, that's why in my question I created folder `a` with 777 and put file `b` inside, which makes user2222 be able to `cp`, `rm` and `mv` that file. "By design only owner can change metadata" I feel I reiterated this too many times now. I _understand_ it is like that right now, I am asking _why_ is it like that. I see no good reason for that decision. Saying "it's like that" or "possibly there are some security issues" is not an explanation. What are those issues? What security does forbidding `chown` give us when they can `cp`, `rm` and `mv`?

Comment: @levantpied why `chown` should check parent directory and file permissions of files to perform it's task? it's not a good practice, it makes maintenance and debug of issues harder. ownership and permissions are separate concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Only `root` or a process with the capability `CAP_CHOWN` can change a file owner (see `man capabilities`).

But you can use ACLs for setting special permissions for certain users or groups (see `man setfacl`).

With NFSv4 ACLs you can even give non-owner users or groups the permission to change the ACLs (which is usually limited to root, the file owner, and processes with `CAP_FOWNER`), see `man nfs4_acl`.

Comment: I'll look into setfacl, but the rest doesn't really answer my question though. I'm not asking what the user can do, but why is the user not allowed to take the ownership of the file that it can otherwise fully access (read, write, rename, delete). I don't see the rationale for that.

Comment: @levantpied I would say that the intention of your question is not clear then. You may improve that. Ownership is more powerful than write permission; that is probably the main argument. The new owner could make the file accessible to new people (which can be checked but is not obvious). He could even prevent the old owner from accessing it.

Comment: `The new owner could make the file accessible to new people` If they can read the file, then they can `cp` it, with similar repercusions. `He could even prevent the old owner from accessing it.` They could `rm` it with similar effect. `I would say that the intention of your question is not clear then.` Not sure how to reword my question, perhaps like this: if you gave someone sufficient permissions on the file, why would reading, writing, renaming, deleting be acceptable, but changing ownership not?